# CSS duplicated without encapsulation breaks another unrelated component

Tags: css, angular, typescript, web

For some reason the CSS file for one of my component is not being encapsulated property. The component is using the default `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` and is in fact parsed with Angular encapsulation.

But for some reason the non-parsed rules also seem to apply, and from the moment the file is loaded for the component its rules now apply to the entire page.

Here you can see the encapsulated selectors and the base ones, both coming from the same file and line.

[image: From chrome DevTools]

None of my other components seems to be having this issue, and I have no idea what could produce this.

Excerpts for more context:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-shot-group',
    templateUrl: './shot-group.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./shot-group.component.css']
})
export class ShotGroupComponent implements OnInit {

    shots: Shot[];
    setup: Setup;
    name: string;
```

Here the component the `shot-group.component.css` bleeds into (that I can see, but I believe it bleeds everywhere):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-property-table',
    templateUrl: './property-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./property-table.component.css'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PropertyTableComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() element?: LabElement;
```

These two don't ever appear at the same time on the page. The CSS fails once the `shot-group` component is created for the first time.

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz with us? Also, please show us the code in your component.ts, have you changed the Encapsulated propriety?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce it in Stackblitz, but I'm adding some excerpts in my question for info